# Why would the Docky launcher stop and disappear when I empty the trash when unmounting a removable drive?

Tags: docky

After I finish working with a removable flash drive I click eject icon in nautilus. If it is appropriate I get a dialog asking if I would like to empty the trash before it un-mounts. I click yes and everything works fine except my Docky launcher disappears. All I need to do is go up to the menu and re-start it, but that can't be right, and I'm not sure how to make it quit. If it matters I have the Trash, and Mounter docklets running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with the [Mounter docklet](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Mounter_Docklet): https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/552657

Comment: I would like to track and maybe comment that in my case it is consistent based on the trash issue. Is there any way to confirm that my crash is the same as this one (since no one mentions the correlation), is that posted info coming from a log file, do I need to start Docky from a command line, or exactly where can that evidence be found?

Comment: @Dennis If you have Docky starting up on login, check `~/.xsession-errors` for anything related to Docky. You could also run Docky from the terminal and post the stack trace in your bug comment.

Comment: install bug-buddy and docky-dbg if you are at all unsure.